# VBS to create scheduled task

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, elevated-privileges

I found this code on the net to create a scheduled task, but I also need to add code that will make the task run with elevated privileges (ie bypass UAC) as well as run the task immediately if the scheduled run time is missed. Have searched high and low for the syntax to no avail. By the way I am not familiar with VBS at all, only python and java, but my company codes all their scripts in VBS. So please explain the solution to a total VBS novice. Thanks.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objNewJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")
errJobCreated = objNewJob.Create _
    ("C:\DDR Tools\Ninite.exe", "********120000.000000-480", _
        True , 1 OR 16, , True, JobID) 
Wscript.Echo errJobCreated
```

Comment: This method is quite old and only supports a fraction of the option of the task scheduler (basically the ones that were possible at the time it was introduced). It's pre vista so elevation was unnecessary. As Serenity posted in the answer you can use schtasks for more options. Although schtasks also does not support switches for every possible option in the taskscheduler it has an /XML switch which allows the import of any task you creted in the gui and exported to XML format as fallback.

Answer (score 2):

Use command line.

```
schtasks /create /s computer /u user /p password /ru RunasUser /tn JobName /rl HIGHEST /tr programname /st 14:30 /sc daily
```